# Why does my for loop not step up?

Tags: vba, excel

This is likely to be a simple issue that I have overlooked. I have a for loop that is refusing to step up with the given interval. The code below is an extract from a more complex code. My program was running for 1h, with no change and I manged to narrow it down to this segment that was causing the large run time.

I have tried running this code in its own module and the same issue happens. I have other for loops within the main bulk of code that have no issue with `step` it's just this one. Any help in finding where I've gone wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Test()


Dim h As Long
Dim BiezerP0 As Double
Dim BiezerP1 As Double
Dim BiezerP2 As Double
Dim BiezerP3 As Double
Dim BiezerValue As Double
Dim BiezerStepInterval As Double
Dim BiezerLocation As Double
Dim P0Time As Double

BiezerStepInterval = 0.167


            For h = 0 To 1 Step BiezerStepInterval

                BiezerP0 = ((1 - h) ^ 3) * P0
                BiezerP1 = 3 * ((1 - h) ^ 2) * h * P1
                BiezerP2 = 3 * (1 - h) * h * h * P2
                BiezerP3 = h * h * h * P3

                BiezerValue = BiezerP0 + BiezerP1 + BiezerP2 + BiezerP3

                BiezerLocation = h * BiezerSteps
                Cells(BiezerLocation + 4, 15) = BiezerValue
                Cells(BiezerLocation + 4, 16) = P0Time + (0.02 * BiezerLocation)


            Next h
End Sub
```

The only issue I can think of causing this is the fact 0.167 doesn't go directly into 1. Would that affect it?

Comment: You need to declare h as Double, not Long (which is integer). And it will go to 1.002.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

h should be a Double, not long

```
Dim h As Double
```

Comment: I was very quick off the mark, but just happened to be here and see it.

Answer (score 2):

As Magnetron said, `h` should be a `Double`, the reason being that assigning `0.167` to a `Long` will result in a `Long` value of `0` - as can be seen in the Immediate window:

```
?Clng(0.167)
 0
```

Adding `0.167` to the `0`, and assigning the result to a Long, will *again* result in a `Long` value of `0`....

Rinse... Repeat...

That's why the variable won't increment. But change the variable type to a `Double` and you won't lose the precision.